# RiverPod context.read doesn't expects an argument

Tags: flutter, riverpod

So I've started working with RiverPod.
When trying to read context.read(myProvider) I get this message:

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
```

I'm using flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+3

Going to the read function definition - I get to the provider.dart file which has this function:

```
 T read<T>() {
    return Provider.of<T>(this, listen: false);
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete code example?

Answer (score 1):

So - I found out that flutter_bloc and flutter_riverpod have some overlapping.

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart' show BlocBuilder, BlocProvider;
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should call it like this:
`context.read<myProvider>();`
where myProvider is the type of your provider

As you can see in the definition, read does not accept arguments.
It uses generics: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

**EDIT**

Check this issue:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/214#issuecomment-781030552